# How can I save multiple audio files?

Tags: android, audio, sharedpreferences

I just started working on an audio recorder app.  So far, the app can record audio and play it.  My end goal is to be able to save multiple audio files to the device.  How would I do this?  Can I use SharedPreferences?  I haven't been able to find anything.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button play;
Button stop;
Button record;
private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
private String outputFile = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    record=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(false);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";;

                myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
                myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                myAudioRecorder.start();
            }

            catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            stop.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAudioRecorder.stop();
            myAudioRecorder.release();
            myAudioRecorder  = null;

            play.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException,SecurityException,IllegalStateException {
            MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                m.setDataSource(outputFile);
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                m.prepare();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            m.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it's already doing what you want, except that you need to assign a new name for every recording? It should be very easy to generate a new filename with every onClick event on the record button... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: How would I generate a new filename on every onClick?  My goal is to display all the files in a listview.

Comment: The easiest way would be to append a date/timestamp to the file name. Concerning the ListView: Then you should mention this goal in your original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder in your external storage and store each file with a timestamp appended to the name of the file.

You can list all the video / audio files stored in this folder and select which video / audio you want to play anytime.

Get all files

```
public void displayAllFilesInFolder() {
    List<String> filepath = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (!hasSDCard()) {
        return;
    }
    File dir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "folderName");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        return;
    }
    File listAllFiles[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listAllFiles != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listAllFiles.length; i++) {
            if (!listAllFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                filepath.add(listAllFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check if SD is mounted

```
private boolean hasSDCard(){
    Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    if(isSDPresent)        {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I have undated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're already saving it to a file:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
```

You just need to add more logic to pick a filename that doesn't already exist.